# Must data-val-required and data-val-number have the same error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Must `data-val-required` and `data-val-number` have the same error messages?

I am just wondering as I am viewing the generated output of my HTML.

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Countries)
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
               @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    m => m.CountryId,
                    new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Id", "Name", Model.CountryId),
                    "-- Select --",
                    new { @class = "form-control" }
               )
          </div>
     </div>
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CountryId)
</div>
```

My viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     public MyViewModel()
     {
          Countries = Enumerable.Empty<CountryDTO>();
     }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
     public int CountryId { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Country")]
     public IEnumerable<CountryDTO> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

The generated HTML from the above looks like this:

```
<select name="CountryId" id="CountryId" data-val-required="Country is required" data-val-number="The field CountryId must be a number." data-val="true" class="form-control">
     <option value="">-- Select --</option>
     <option value="1">country 1</option>
     <option value="2">country 2</option>
     <option value="3">country 3</option>
     <option value="4">country 4</option>
</select>
```

Why do `data-val-required` and `data-val-number` have 2 different messages?  Don't they need to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

No, required is displayed when the user didn't provide any input at all, while number is displayed when the provided input isn't a number.

You can see it also in a way that in the required-error message you can provide the user with information, why the field is required, while in the number-error message you can provide the user with additional information, why the field needs to be numeric.

Comment: That number error message is the default error message? How do I override it with my error message? I don't want to have my property information in the error message.

Comment: That's a good question, so far I only used Range to check and I couldn't find anything really helpful either in the [DataAnnotations Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) nor in the [DataType Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used together with the [DataType Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)